# Oracle 23c ROUND with DATE data type

Tags: sql, oracle, date, rounding

I have encountered an odd behaviour of Oracle 23c. As far as I understand lack of the second parameter in the ROUND function should work exactly the same as putting there explicitly 'DAY' parameter.

```
  SELECT TO_DATE('2024-06-26 15:02:18','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')               AS result                     
     , ROUND(TO_DATE('2024-06-26 15:02:18','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')     )         AS default_result
     , ROUND(TO_DATE('2024-06-26 15:02:18','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')   , 'DAY')    AS day_explicit
  ;
```

According to the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/ROUND-date.html#GUID-C6D342D0-6068-4986-A759-70EF4599EC41) "If you omit fmt, then date is rounded to the nearest day" and 'DAY' parameter means simply DAY.

The result looks like this -> Shouldn't day_explicit column be like **2024-06-27**?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ROUND(date_value, 'DAY')` is rounding to the nearest start of the week (as defined by the `NLS_TERRITORY` session/database parameter).

`ROUND(date_value, 'DD')` is rounding to the nearest day.

This is documented in the [ROUND and TRUNC Date Functions documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ROUND-and-TRUNC-Date-Functions.html#GUID-8E10AB76-21DA-490F-A389-023B648DDEF8):

> | Format Model | Rounding or Truncating Unit |
> | --- | --- |
> | DDD DD J | Day |
> | DAY DY D | Starting day of the week |

---

For example:

If you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt) AS
SELECT TRUNC(DATE '2024-06-26', 'IW') + LEVEL - 1 + INTERVAL '15:02:18' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;
```

And you use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Germany'
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)';
SELECT dt,
       ROUND(dt)        AS default_result,
       ROUND(dt, 'DAY') AS day_explicit,
       ROUND(dt, 'DD') AS dd_explicit
FROM   table_name;
```

Then the output is:

| DT | DEFAULT_RESULT | DAY_EXPLICIT | DD_EXPLICIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-06-24 15:02:18 (MON) | 2024-06-25 00:00:00 (TUE) | 2024-06-24 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-06-25 00:00:00 (TUE) |
| 2024-06-25 15:02:18 (TUE) | 2024-06-26 00:00:00 (WED) | 2024-06-24 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-06-26 00:00:00 (WED) |
| 2024-06-26 15:02:18 (WED) | 2024-06-27 00:00:00 (THU) | 2024-06-24 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-06-27 00:00:00 (THU) |
| 2024-06-27 15:02:18 (THU) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) |
| 2024-06-28 15:02:18 (FRI) | 2024-06-29 00:00:00 (SAT) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-06-29 00:00:00 (SAT) |
| 2024-06-29 15:02:18 (SAT) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) |
| 2024-06-30 15:02:18 (SUN) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) |

Since in most of Europe, the start of the week is Monday.

If you use the same query in a different territory:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'America'
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)';
SELECT dt,
       ROUND(dt)        AS default_result,
       ROUND(dt, 'DAY') AS day_explicit,
       ROUND(dt, 'DD') AS dd_explicit
FROM   table_name;
```

Then the output is:

| DT | DEFAULT_RESULT | DAY_EXPLICIT | DD_EXPLICIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-06-24 15:02:18 (MON) | 2024-06-25 00:00:00 (TUE) | 2024-06-23 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-06-25 00:00:00 (TUE) |
| 2024-06-25 15:02:18 (TUE) | 2024-06-26 00:00:00 (WED) | 2024-06-23 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-06-26 00:00:00 (WED) |
| 2024-06-26 15:02:18 (WED) | 2024-06-27 00:00:00 (THU) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-06-27 00:00:00 (THU) |
| 2024-06-27 15:02:18 (THU) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) |
| 2024-06-28 15:02:18 (FRI) | 2024-06-29 00:00:00 (SAT) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-06-29 00:00:00 (SAT) |
| 2024-06-29 15:02:18 (SAT) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) |
| 2024-06-30 15:02:18 (SUN) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) |

As Oracle considers the start of the week in the USA to be Sunday.

If you do:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'Bangladesh'
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (DY)';
SELECT dt,
       ROUND(dt)        AS default_result,
       ROUND(dt, 'DAY') AS day_explicit,
       ROUND(dt, 'DD') AS dd_explicit
FROM   table_name;
```

Then the output is:

| DT | DEFAULT_RESULT | DAY_EXPLICIT | DD_EXPLICIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-06-24 15:02:18 (MON) | 2024-06-25 00:00:00 (TUE) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-06-25 00:00:00 (TUE) |
| 2024-06-25 15:02:18 (TUE) | 2024-06-26 00:00:00 (WED) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-06-26 00:00:00 (WED) |
| 2024-06-26 15:02:18 (WED) | 2024-06-27 00:00:00 (THU) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-06-27 00:00:00 (THU) |
| 2024-06-27 15:02:18 (THU) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) |
| 2024-06-28 15:02:18 (FRI) | 2024-06-29 00:00:00 (SAT) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-06-29 00:00:00 (SAT) |
| 2024-06-29 15:02:18 (SAT) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-06-30 00:00:00 (SUN) |
| 2024-06-30 15:02:18 (SUN) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) | 2024-06-28 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2024-07-01 00:00:00 (MON) |

As the start of the week is Friday in Bangladesh.

Similarly, if you set the `NLS_TERRITORY` to a country in the Middle East then you would mostly find that the week starts on Saturday.

*Note: If you want to always round to Monday then use the `IW` format model for the start of the ISO week (as defined by ISO 8601).*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jXInX782)

Comment: You are right, thank you. I overlooked the difference between DD and DAY..